# How to parse date/time from a string in C++

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, string-conversion, boost-date-time

How to convert string with template `"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"` (for example, *28.05.2013 17:42:00*) to `boost::posix_time::ptime` or something similar?

The following is my non-working code.

```
boost::posix_time::ptime stringToDateTime(const std::string &text) {
  const std::locale fct
  (   std::locale::classic()
  ,   new boost::gregorian::date_input_facet("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
  );
  std::istringstream is(text);
  is.imbue(fct);
  boost::posix_time::ptime date;
  is >> date;
  return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boost::posix_time::ptime stringToDateTime(const std::string &text) {
  const std::locale fct
  (   std::locale::classic()
  ,   new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
  );           //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - that was an error
  std::istringstream is(text);
  is.imbue(fct);
  boost::posix_time::ptime date;
  is >> date;
  return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an ugly way I don't to accept

```
boost::posix_time::ptime stringToDateTime(const std::string &text) {
  return boost::posix_time::time_from_string
  (   text.substr(6, 4) // year
  +   "-"
  +   text.substr(3, 2) // month
  +   "-"
  +   text.substr(0, 2) // day
  +   text.substr(10, 9) // hour,min,sec
  );
}
```